# Is Xindy a complete replacement of makeindex?

Tags: indexing, xindy

I am working with a current TexLive using XeLaTeX for LaTeX, biber for bibliography and makeindex for the index. I never really got my glossary requirements fixed (right now it is not even printing it at all). While searching for a solution I stumbled over xindy telling me with internationalization (which I indeed would like to have [english, chinese and arabic at the moment within a german document]) I should do xindy.

Is xindy indeed a complete replacement for makeindex, so that I should change my current normal index to xindy and fix my glossary-headache using xindy?

The pretty much empty (also I removed all newcommand and so forth only keeping the usepackage to test if all my stuff still works, so in that way it is the minimum working example)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}%[a4paper,oneside]

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\setotherlanguages{english, greek}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[xindy={language=german, codepage=utf8}, style=altlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[xindy, splitindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false,
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{itteerde.bib}
\bibliography{itteerde} 

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pictex}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,arrows}

\usepackage{verse}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[position=top]{caption}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{etaremune}

\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\raggedright}{}{}

\makeindex
\makeglossaries

\begin{titlepage}
\title{Meine Chance\\Projektarbeit und IT-Basics}

\author{Erik Itter}
\end{titlepage}    

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Recherche}\index{Rechercher}
\chapter{Projektarbeit}\index{Projektarbeit}

\chapter{Präsentation}
\section{Dokument/ Ausarbeitung}
\section{Vortrag}

\chapter{Techniken}
\section{Mind-Map}\index{Techniken!Mind-Map}\index{Mind-Map}

\newglossaryentry{computer}
{
  name=computer,
  description={is a programmable machine that receives input,
               stores and manipulates data, and provides
               output in a useful format}
}

\printglossary
\printindex
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: going forward hoping in the right direction while hoping for answers/commnets...

Do I execute xindy, texxindy or ...? For the glossary, for the index?

Comment: Seems to be the wrong tool for me. Checking nomenclature next.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Unrelated but you need to load `glossaries` after `hyperref` not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more or less a replacement. Read the user-manual of glossaries package to determine what you need. Mostly sorting non-latin1 script makes the difference.